# Error cannot find module 'json-stringify-safe'

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, npm, ionic2, node-modules

Getting an error when running command - **ionic serve**

The same code was running in another system, perhaps not working for me now.

[image]

Comment: please, can you run `ionic info` to see your versions. Anyway do you tried `npm i json-stringify-safe`?

Comment: Running ionic info is throwing the same error!

Also, I tried running - npm i json-stringify-safe | still not working.

Comment: try to install nvm https://github.com/creationix/nvm, then run `nvm install 5.11.0` or other node version you want and then install again ionic cli with `npm i -g ionic`

Comment: mh.. have you tried to simply run `npm install json-stringify-safe`? Afaik it's not a package included by Ionic per default, so if it's not contained in your package.json and therefore not installed when doing an initial `npm install`, then this error wouldn't be surprising at all ;)

Comment: It's the same with me when system show Can not find module : "abc". I just run npm install abc. Then they will run correctly.

Comment: Thanks ALL, finally worked! That worked when I uninstalled node and then reinstalled with version node-v4.6.1-x86

Answer (score 1):

Please run the following command to install 'json-stringify-safe'

```
npm install json-stringify-safe
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ALL, finally worked! That worked when I uninstalled node and then reinstalled with version node-v4.6.1-x86

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by the stringify extension. You can load it with the following code.

```
npm install json-stable-stringify
```

Answer (score 0):

Running this code fixed it on windows 10:

```
npm install fast-json-stable-stringify
```

As stated on their web page https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-json-stable-stringify